# How to create element and set custom attribute to map a simple type class property

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
@XmlRootElement(name="flowPane")
public class Image implements Serializable {
    public  String name;
    public  String description;
}
```

Bound to

```
<flowPane>
    <label text="name"/>
    <label text="description"/>
</flowPane>
```

Tried simply placing @XmlAttribute and @XmlElement annotations on the name and description properties but neither is the solution that I'm looking for.

Comment: Which XML do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry don't understand your question. The XML that I want to achieve is     <flowPane><label text="name"/><label text="description"/></flowPane>, with the text attributes containing the corresponding values of course.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was thinking of something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap the fields with a new class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="flowPanel")
public class Image implements Serializable {

    public static class Label {
        @XmlAttribute()
        public String text;

        public Label(){}

        public Label(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }   
    }

    @XmlElement(name="label")
    public Label name;
    @XmlElement(name="label")
    public Label description;    
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to avoid adding more classes, but if there's no other way, I'll implement this solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Standard JAXB APIs

In order to get the same element to appear multiple times in an XML document you are going to need a `List` property.  Note in the example below label will have a property mapped to the `text` attribute.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="flowPanel")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Image implements Serializable {

   @XmlElement(name="label").
   private List<Label> labels;

}
```

---

### `@XmlPath` extension in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)

If you are using [**EclipseLink MOXy**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider then you could leverage the `@XmlPath` extension we added for this use case.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="flowPane")
public class Image implements Serializable {
    @XmlPath("label[1]/@text")
    public  String name;

    @XmlPath("label[1]/@text")
    public  String description;
}
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about this on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html